# JQuery toggleClass not working in React.js when i try to click on the element

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

If i try to toggle the class(active) nothing hapens just flashing in the dev tools.
[Here is the picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQOqW.png)

And here is my code:

```js
let usercontainer = document.querySelector(".user-container")
let user = document.querySelector(".user")
    
$(user).on('click', function() {
    $(usercontainer).toggleClass(".active")
})
```

Here is how i render:

```
<div className="user">
                <img className="upic" src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/477814830598717441/3d84322f38d500a46e017951569a8c42.webp?size=1024" alt="usericon" />
                <a className="uname">F4||1ng</a>
                <div className="user-container">
                    <div className="logout-container">
                        <div className="logout">Kijelentkezés</div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="notes-container">
                        <div className="notes">Jegyzeteim</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Can you provide the code that renders the user container element?

Comment: Other note: Avoid jQuery with React, React has many efficient ways to handle events and the DOM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few tips here:

- Use the `$` shortcut instead of document.querySelector
- When using toggleClass, use the class name without the dot in front.

Something like this:

```js
let usercontainer = $(".user-container")
$(".user").on('click', function() {
  usercontainer.toggleClass("active")
})
```

See https://codepen.io/jr-duboc/pen/NWXepRG

Comment: Not working does the same thing!

Comment: Then possibly the issue comes from the HTML.
Where is/are your `user` elements ?

Comment: I edited the question you can look at it

Comment: I see where you got confused...in HTML you need to use `class="<class Name>"`, not `className`.
`className` is JSX notation (React).
I've updated the codepen accordingly.

Comment: If you're mixing React and Jquery together to do this though, my advice is ... don't. Just use React for everything, your life will be much simpler.

Comment: How can i do that with just only react?

Comment: Probably by adding an onClick function on the appropriate element, with a state change somewhere to update your class...

Comment: I will try thanks for the responses